# Proof of $z^{-1 + \epsilon} = \frac{1}{\epsilon} \delta(z) + \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^k}{k!} \left( \frac{\ln z}{z} \right)_+$

Tags: distribution-theory

I came across this formula in some paper $$z^{-1 + \epsilon} = \frac{1}{\epsilon} \delta(z) + \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^k}{k!} \left( \frac{\ln z}{z} \right)_+$$ Where the plus indicates the plus distribution and $\delta$ is the usual delta function.

There is no proof given nor is there any reference to an other paper. Does anybody have an idea how to prove this?

Comment: I wonder if you can give a link to the paper you are reading.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.4384.pdf Under A.8 you'll find the identity. But I don't think it'll do you any help xD.

Comment: There is a deleted answer which doesn't explain the $\ln(z)/z$ notation and is missing the delta term but has essentially the correct idea. Define $(\ln^k(z)/z)_+$ to mean the distributional derivative of $\ln^{k + 1}(z) H(z)/(k + 1)$. Then the correct formula is
$$(z^{-1 + \epsilon})_+ =
\frac 1 \epsilon \delta(z) +
 \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac {\epsilon^k} {k!}
  \left( \frac {\ln^k z} z \right)_+.$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just found another paper where the formula has $\ln^k z $ instead of $\ln z$ so it's probably a typo.

Comment: @Maxim Hello. It's been quite a while.  I hope that you're doing well.  You mentioned that  $\psi_k=\left( \frac {\ln^k z} z \right)_+$ is defined such that for any $\phi \in \mathbb{S}$, $\langle \psi, \phi \rangle = -\frac1{k+1}\int_0^\infty \log^{k+1}(z) \phi'(z)\,dz$.  Is that correct?  So, just curious ... what is the definition of $(z^{-1+\varepsilon})_+$?

Comment: @MarkViola Hi Mark, that's exactly right, $(\ln^k(z)/z)_+$ is defined as in your comment. For $a > 0$, $(z^{a - 1})_+$ is a regular distribution,
$$((z^{a - 1})_+, \phi) =
\int_{\mathbb R^+} z^{a - 1} \phi(z) \, dz.$$
For $-1 < a < 0$, we define
$$((z^{a - 1})_+, \phi) =
\int_{\mathbb R^+} z^{a - 1} (\phi(z) - \phi(0)) \, dz.$$
For $a \leq -1$, the distributional limit
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^N \frac {a^k} {k!} \psi_k$$
doesn't exist (which can be shown by taking $\phi$ s.t. $\phi'(z) = 1$ for all $z \in [0, 1]$).

Comment: One can rewrite the $+$distribution as 
\begin{equation} 
\langle ( z^{-1 + \epsilon} )_+ |\phi\rangle =\langle z^{-1 + \epsilon} - \delta(z) \int_z^\infty dy\;y^{\epsilon - 1}| \phi \rangle = \langle z^{-1 + \epsilon} + 1/\epsilon z^{\epsilon} \delta(z)| \phi \rangle.
\end{equation}
On the other hand we can expand the left hand side directly, yielding 
\begin{equation} 
(z^{-1 + \epsilon})_+ = \sum_i \frac{\epsilon^k}{k!} \left( \frac{\ln^k z}{z} \right)_+.
\end{equation}
As mentioned by the above comments, the distribution is defined over $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\epsilon \in (-1, 0)$.

Comment: But how does one continue from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\varepsilon >0$, we define the distribution $\psi_{\varepsilon}(z)=\left(z^{\varepsilon - 1}\right)_+$ as

$$\langle \psi_\varepsilon , \phi\rangle = \int_0^\infty z^{\varepsilon - 1}\phi(z)\,dz$$

Integrating by parts with $u=\phi$ and $v=\frac{z^\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\langle \psi_\varepsilon , \phi\rangle &= -\frac1\varepsilon\int_0^\infty z^{\varepsilon }\phi'(z)\,dz\\\\
&=-\frac1\varepsilon\int_0^\infty e^{\varepsilon \log(z)}\phi'(z)\,dz\\\\
&=\frac{\phi(0)}{\varepsilon}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\varepsilon^{k}}{(k+1)!}\int_0^\infty \log^{k+1}(z) \phi'(z)\,dz\\\\
&=\frac{\phi(0)}{\varepsilon}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\varepsilon^{k}}{k!}\int_0^\infty \left(-\frac{\log^{k+1}(z)}{k+1}\right) \phi'(z)\,dz\\\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we can write in distribution that

$$\left(z^{\varepsilon - 1}\right)_+=\frac1\varepsilon \delta(z)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\varepsilon^k}{k!}\left(\frac{\log^k(z)}{z}\right)_+$$

where the distribution $\ell_k(z)=\left(\frac{\log^k(z)}{z}\right)_+$ is defined as

$$\langle \ell_k,\phi\rangle = \int_0^\infty \left(-\frac{\log^{k+1}(z)}{k+1}\right)\phi'(z)\,dz$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: I got a couple of questions. First, how would one conduct the proof for $\epsilon < 0$. One would get pretty nasty boundary terms if I'm not mistaken. Second, how can you define new distributions through the plus-distribution? Shouldn't for instance $\psi_\epsilon$ be defined as $$\int_0^\infty dz \; z^{\epsilon - 1} (\phi(z) - \phi(0))$$. Same goes for $$ \langle l_k|\phi \rangle = \int_0^\infty dz \left(\frac{\ln^k z}{z} \right) (\phi(z) - \phi(0))$$. As a followup question: How do you go about the boundary terms in the last step?

Comment: The result herein was applicable for $\varepsilon>0$.  For $-1<\varepsilon<0$, we need to define the distribution $\psi_\varepsilon(z)=\left(z^{\varepsilon-1}\right)_+$ as $$\langle \psi, \phi\rangle =\int_0^\infty z^{\varepsilon-1}(\phi(z)-\phi(0))\,dz$$.  For the case $\varepsilon>0$, we use the regular distribution (without $\phi(0)$).  In the last step, we are simply using the definition of the distributional derivative.  If $\psi$ is any distribution, then for any $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$, by defintion $\langle \psi',\phi\rangle =-\langle \psi, \phi'\rangle$